# Getting the value of particular column when its only one row in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Below is the dataframe:

|  | date | open |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 26 | 15-09-21 | 406.5 |

Now I need the value of open so I tried:- `print(df.open)`

It gave error:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'open'

column types are as follow: `print(df.dtypes)`

> date ---->           object
>
> open ---->         float64

Comment: It works for me... Are you sure that you didn't accidentally leave an extra trailing whitespace in the column name?

Comment: yes, the column name is having extra whitespace in starting, like: **' open'**. How can I remove it? @U12-Forward

Comment: Check my answer cc. soji

Answer (score 1):

To strip the whitespaces:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
df.open
```

Or:

```
df.set_axis(df.columns.str.strip(), axis=1).open
```

You still could get columns like:

```
df[" open"]
```

Comment: Can you convert to wiki because dupe?

Comment: @jezrael oakkay

Comment: Why create dupes? Why I have to again and again ask for wiki? It is so problem google answer and close, not only me?

Comment: There is a lot of answer for stripping columns names :(

Comment: @jezrael Sorry, will do in teh futre

Answer (score 0):

To remove whitespace in header use this:

```
df.rename(columns = lambda x: x.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a white space in your " open" column, just rename it by `df = df.rename(columns={' open':'open'})`

I sometimes prefer to call a specific pandas column using this `df["open"]` and press "Tab" for the auto-complete (in Jupyter Notebook or in Vscode). That way I am aware of any concealed typos such as that whitespace which you have